# Statement for checking IF multiple cells CONTAIN certain text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, contains, sumifs

I have a column of values, and then I have two columns with simple marking like just an 'X':

```
     A              B               C
1    
2
3    VALUES:       PERSON1:         PERSON2
4    500           X
5    180                            X
6    100                            X
7    200           X
8    TOTAL:
9    =SUM(A4:A8)   ??               ??
```

Can I create a statement that will check that if a box has an `X` in it the value of the A-column cell on the same row will be subtracted from the total summation?

In the example above PERSON2 should have a statement with the values '=980-180-100' which is `700`.

I can easily do it for one cell: `=IF(B4="X", A9-A4)` but I can't quite get around with doing with multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  suspect:

```
=SUM(A4:A7)-SUMIF(B4:B7,"X",A4:A7)
```

is what you are after, or perhaps:

```
=SUM(A4:A7)-2*SUMIF(B4:B7,"X",A4:A7)
```

but a better solution is from @barry houdini:

> in B9 try this formula copied to C9 `=SUMIF(B4:B7,"<>X",$A4:$A7)`

Comment: ...or perhaps sum when value is not "X", e.g. in B9 try this formula copied to C9 `=SUMIF(B4:B7,"<>X",$A4:$A7)`

Comment: haha, Yeah I was way to quick with my example that i discarded a few 100 ;)
This is exactly what I wanted :) thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like 
`=$A9-SUMIFS($A4:$A7,B4:B7,"X")`